How to get $a$ values so that the system of following equations have no solutions or many solutions or just one solution?
For the system $x+y+z = 0,\ ax + 4z = 5,\ ax +ay + 4z = 5$, find all the values of such (a) that the system has:

No solution.
Many solutions.
Unique solution.

In this problem I tried to solve it the following way:
Reducing the augmented matrix, and applying the condition for no solution case for the first one, which is $\text{Rank}(A)\neq \text{Rank}(A_{\text{augmented}})$.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &\bigm| 0\\
a & 0 & 4 &\bigm| 1\\
a & a & 4 &\bigm| 5\\
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &\bigm| 0\\
0 & -a & 4-a &\bigm| 1\\
0 & 0 & 4-a &\bigm| 5\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
And then taking the determinant of that matrix to get some expression from which I can use the condition of no solution case.
$$
\text{det}
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
0 & -a & 4-a\\
0 & 0 & 4-a\\
\end{bmatrix}
\right) = -a(4-a) = a^2-4a 
$$
And get the determinant of the $\text{Rank}(A_{augmented})$:
$$
\text{det}
\left(
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0\\
-a & 4-a & 1\\
0 & 4-a & 5\\
\end{bmatrix}
\right) = a-4 + 5(4-a - (-a)) = a + 16
$$
Applying the condition that:  $a^2-4a \neq a + 16,\ \therefore a^2-5a-16 \neq 0$
The problem is that that kind of solution doesn't yield any integer solutions, and the solution that was done by the TA was too much trivial than mine, actually it was better because it was just trivial.
The solution of my TA was:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &\bigm| 0\\
a & 0 & 4 &\bigm| 1\\
a & a & 4 &\bigm| 5\\
\end{bmatrix}
\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 &\bigm| 0\\
0 & -a & 4-a &\bigm| 1\\
0 & 0 & 4-a &\bigm| 5\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence by inspection, in case of no solution for the system, (a) is equal to (4, 0)

What exactly is your question?

It's first line showing the matrix and asking to obtain values of a for the tree cases mentioned.

You complicated by using the matrix form, subtracting eq2 and eq3 you immediately get $ay=0$.

if $a=0$ then $z=\frac 45$ and $x+y+\frac 45=0$ and this has infinitely many solutions.

if $a\neq 0$ then $y=0\implies z=-x\implies (a-4)x=5$

if $a=4$ there is no solution since $0=5$ is absurd.

if $a\neq 0,4$ then $x=\frac 5{a-4},y=0,z=\frac{-5}{a-4}$ unique solution


